# How to preserve leading zero in OLE DB Source output column?

Tags: ssis, ssis-2008

I am using SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services) and using the Ole DB Source Component.

One of the columns is specified as DataType: DT_NUMERIC, Precision: 18, Scale: 4.
When the number to the left of the decimal is zero, the zero gets truncated.

```
0.1234 becomes  .1234  (I want 0.1234)
```

Is there a simple solution to preserving the zero, or do I need to create a derived column and convert the value to a string and pad it with a zero as needed?

Edit:
Please close this as a duplicate of [How do I get SSIS Data Flow to put '0.00' in a flat file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868348/how-do-i-get-ssis-data-flow-to-put-0-00-in-a-flat-file).

Comment: What is your destination component: database table, text file, etc.?  If a text file, then apply a derived column.  If a database table, then try modifying the Input Output Parameters setting the value to a decimal scale of 2.  Take a look at the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868348/how-do-i-get-ssis-data-flow-to-put-0-00-in-a-flat-file

Comment: Destination is a text file (CSV). The scale is already correct but it looks like I'll use a derived column. Thanks