# include leading zeros while exporting to csv in ssis

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, etl, export-to-csv

I have a package which exports data from table to .csv file, it exports 600 000 records.

I have few columns which has leading zeros and trailing zeros, while exporting the data both leading and trailing zeros are missing.

EX: actual data coming from source

```
 column1   column2  
 001       67.50
```

exported data in csv file

```
 column1   column2  
 1         67.5
```

I tried many methods like placing **data conversion**, and also **Replicate function** in derived column.

i also tried by exporting the data to .txt file and use .cmd file to change the .txt file .csv file, all these methods yielded no results.

is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: make sure the destination is a text column. if that doesn't work, try quote wrapping text.

Comment: How did u tried to open .CSV file from destination ?

Comment: what are the SSIS datatypes of the affected columns?   Check the outputs of the source component.

Answer (score 1):

When exporting to text- or csv-formatted files numeric values that need to retain leading and/or trailing zeros, a combination of the following is required.

1) Using a derived column or conversion task under Data Flow, convert the numeric field to a text or varchar.

2) Be sure the destination CSV file has the field defined as a text of sufficient character length.

Lastly, if you are in a situation where a numerical value is required (NULL or blank are not acceptable) in the output file, then take a look at the following link.  This is where a "0.00" must be provided instead of a NULL or blank.

[How do I get SSIS Data Flow to put '0.00' in a flat file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868348/how-do-i-get-ssis-data-flow-to-put-0-00-in-a-flat-file)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Open the `Flat File Connection manager` used in the Destination csc, Go to `Advanced Tab` change all columns data type to `DT_STR` or `DT_WSTR` *(Note that when data is saved to a flat file, there is no data type taken into consideration)*

If it still not working, then add a derived column that convert these values to `DT_STR` before assigning them to Destination