# How do I convert ",00" data in csv file to "0,00" in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a SSIS package with a Data flow that takes an OLEDB source.
I used codes to take datas from this source.

[image]

this data clearly shows in data viewer of SSIS

BUT

when i open this csv file with notepad, this shows like ",00"

I want to see like "0,00"

My column data type is currently numeric.

How can I fix this situation?

This is killing me

Comment: For which purpose you want to transform ,00 to 0,00 in your source when SSIS is already detecting the values correctly ?

Comment: The zero in front of the decimal point shown is a visual leading zero, not a literal one.  one, open in excel and choose how you want it displayed.  two, control how it look as string instead of numeric.  [see question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868348/how-do-i-get-ssis-data-flow-to-put-0-00-in-a-flat-file)